# lumen/laravel cannot get firebird database

Tags: php, laravel, firebird, lumen

I get project to connect lumen with firebird database.
I can connect with php file. in connectFDB.php .
When I setting .env and config/database.php but not working

ps. I installed this
https://packagist.org/packages/harrygulliford/laravel-firebird

ps. lumen5 laravel7 firebird3.0

connectFDB.php
it can work and get data for me.

```
<?php

$database = "/var/lib/firebird/3.0/data/employee.fdb";
$username ="user";
$password = "pass";

$conn = ibase_connect($database, $username, $password);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

echo "Connected to the database<br>";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE;";
echo $sql."sql<br>";

$result = ibase_query($conn, $sql) or die(ibase_errmsg());
echo $result."result<br>";


while ($row = ibase_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["ID"]." ".$row["NAME"]."<br>";
}

ibase_close($conn);

?>
```

bootstrap/app.php

i regised $app->register(\Firebird\FirebirdServiceProvider::class);

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
(new 
Laravel\Lumen\Bootstrap\LoadEnvironmentVariables(dirname(__DIR__)))->bootstrap();
date_default_timezone_set(env('APP_TIMEZONE', 'UTC'));


$app = new Laravel\Lumen\Application(dirname(__DIR__));
$app->withFacades();
$app->withEloquent();


$app->singleton(
Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler::class,
App\Exceptions\Handler::class);

$app->singleton(
Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class,
App\Console\Kernel::class);


$app->configure('app');
$app->middleware([
   'cors' => App\Http\Middleware\CorsMiddleware::class,
]);


$app->register(App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class);
$app->register(\Firebird\FirebirdServiceProvider::class);


$app->router->group(['namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers',], function 
($router) {
     require __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php';
});

return $app;
```

config/database.php

```
<?php

return array(

    'default' => 'mysql',

    'connections' => array(

        //for connect database
        'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port'      => env('DB_PORT', 3306),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'orisma_hr'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'user'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'pass'),
        ),

        //for connect firebird
        'firebird' => array(
            'driver'    => 'firebird',
            'host'      => env('DB_FIREBIRD_HOST', ''),
            'database'  => env('DB_FIREBIRD_DATABASE', '/var/lib/firebird/3.0/data/employee.fdb'),
            'username'  => env('DB_FIREBIRD_USERNAME', 'user'),
            'password'  => env('DB_FIREBIRD_PASSWORD', 'pass'),
            'charset'   => env('DB_FIREBIRD_CHARSET', 'UTF8'),
        ),
    ),
);
```

.env

```
APP_NAME=Lumen
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=907d908ee0936ea8091fc878f9968c1d

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=orisma_hr
DB_USERNAME=user
DB_PASSWORD=pass

DB_FIREBIRD_HOST=
DB_FIREBIRD_DATABASE=/var/lib/firebird/3.0/data/employee.fdb
DB_FIREBIRD_USERNAME=user
DB_FIREBIRD_PASSWORD=pass
DB_FIREBIRD_CHARSET=UTF8
```

Comment: Why is `DB_FIREBIRD_HOST` empty? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Use http://FBProfiler.sf.net or any other TraceAPI client, connect to your server and see if it even receives any connection requests form your program, anf if it does, whether they were succesful

Comment: Just a tip for the next time: Make sure to remove login credentials before you post some code. This way you can protect your accounts and/or servers.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I don't know they it empty but it can work in connectFDB.php

Comment: Seeing `'default' => 'mysql',` and `DB_CONNECTION=mysql` i do not think your program even tries to look for Firebird. It seem s your program is configured for using MYSQL not any other server

Comment: @Arioch'The When I query can DB::connect('firebird')->table() it know to connect firebird

Comment: @KorakotPhromchaiman hopefully so, just there was nothing like that command in the quoted sources

Answer (score 1):

I got work it

1.chown firebird.firebird /tmp/firebird/fb_init
2.chmod 777 /tmp/firebird/fb_init

3.edit .env

```
DB_FIREBIRD_HOST=localhost
DB_FIREBIRD_USERNAME=sysdba
DB_FIREBIRD_PASSWORD=masterkey(or passwordto set when install firebird)
```

can see user pass in /etc/firebird/3.0/SYSDBA.password

4.edit config/database.php

```
'host'      => env('DB_FIREBIRD_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'username'  => env('DB_FIREBIRD_USERNAME', 'sysdba'),
            'password'  => env('DB_FIREBIRD_PASSWORD', 'masterkey')(or passwordto set when install firebird)
```

Comment: Using chown 777 gives all users access to the Firebird database, that might not be a good idea from a security perspective.